# Trying to write to next line (python/win32com)

Tags: python, win32com

I am able to find the last row and i have my variable set, however i'm getting this error:  This object does not support enumeration

```
## Export Severity to Qualy Data ##
## access excel application and open active worksheet ##
Excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.application')
Excel.Visible = False
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open('Qualys Data.xlsx')
sh = wb.ActiveSheet

## Find last row ##
lastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
next_Row = lastRow+1
print("Next row to print: ", next_Row)

## Can i loop through the document, if on last_Row / print to last row?
for line in sh:
    if desired_row == next_Row:
        sh.Range("A1:A1").Value = reportDate

print("Exporting to data to new spreadsheet...")
time.sleep(1)

Excel.DisplayAlerts = 0
wb.SaveAs('Qualys Data.xlsx')
Excel.DisplayAlerts = True

Excel.Quit()
```

Basically I want to write to the last row if on the last row, next_Row will print the row number to write to

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to iterate on `wb.ActiveSheet` which is why you are getting the error message.

If you are just trying to append a single cell to the bottom of the first row, you can just write directly to that cell, no enumeration is needed:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from datetime import datetime
import time

reportDate = datetime.now()

Excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.application')
Excel.Visible = False

wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(r'e:\python temp\Qualys Data.xlsx')
ws = wb.ActiveSheet

## Find last row ##
lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
next_Row = lastRow + 1
print("Next row to print: ", next_Row)

ws.Cells(next_Row, 1).Value = reportDate

print("Exporting to data to new spreadsheet...")
time.sleep(1)

Excel.DisplayAlerts = 0
wb.SaveAs('Qualys Data.xlsx')
Excel.DisplayAlerts = True
Excel.Quit()
```

This is done using `ws.Cells(next_Row, 1).Value = reportDate`

In this example, it just appends the current date and time.

---

To write a list to the last row use the following:

```
data = ["cell 1", "cell 2", "cell 3", "cell 4"]
ws.Range(ws.Cells(next_Row, 1), ws.Cells(next_Row, len(data))).Value = data
```

Comment: that works perfectly, but i would like add more cells depending on the column, such as col b, c, d, e, f, g and h to the same row

Comment: You can also write a whole list, I have added an example.